# How can I get a scroll window to make everything fit inside of it

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZIwg.png)

[image: Second Image of the desired result]

I'm trying to make this horizontal scroll window centered. However, it cannot do that because inside of it, it is showing everything being stretched. Currently doing this in react with simple HTML and CSS properties. Would like to know if there is a way to make everything fit on the left side while still allowing the scroll feature while having it centered.

```
    .scrollmenu {
  background-color: rgb(236, 235, 235);
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1200px;
  
}

div.scrollmenu .scroll_info {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

.scrollmenu .scroll_info{
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrollmenu .row{
  display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(44, 82, 138);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50px;
}
.scrollmenu .scroll_info .row .click_to_view1{
  width: 50%;
}
.scrollmenu .row .click_to_view1 .column1{
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.scrollmenu .row .click_to_view1 .data_text{
  color: rgb(213,222,238);
  font-weight: 500;
  
}

.scrollmenu .row .click_to_view2 {
  flex: 50%;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.scrollmenu .row .click_to_view2 .column2{
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.scrollmenu .row .click_to_view2 .column2 .image{
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-left: 55px;
}

.article_info .views{
  font-weight:560;
  margin-top: 50px;

}

.article_info .title{
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.article_info .sub-title{
  color: rgb(78, 77, 77);
}

.article_info .body{
  font-weight: 450;
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-right: 90px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.top{
  margin-top: 35px;
  color: rgb(79, 77, 77);
}


.btn{
    background-color: white;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding-left: 50px;
      padding-right: 50px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
      text-decoration: none;
}
.btnImg{
  height: 20%;
  width: 30%;
}
    class Slider extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="scrollmenu">
                {/* <div class="scrollmenu"> */}
                <div className="scroll_info" >
                    <div className="row" {...this.props}>
                        <div className="click_to_view1">
                            <div className="column1">
                                <h2 className="data_text">Kyrie Irving can still technically be traded,but all signs point to
                                </h2>
                                <h2 className="data_text">
                                    him playing for Nets next season.
                                </h2>
                                <h3 className="data_text">Basketball</h3>
                                <h3 className="data_text">2022-6-19</h3>
                                <h3 className="data_text">Tom</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="click_to_view2">
                            <div className="column2">
                                <img
                                    className="image"
                                    alt="Article "
                                    src={require("./HomePage_Images/Article_Img.png")}
                                ></img>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* <a className="scroll_info" href="#home"> */}
                <div className="scroll_info">
                    <div className="row" {...this.props}>
                        <div className="click_to_view1">

                            <div className="column1">
                                <h2 className="data_text">More reporting points to Harden opting out to
                                </h2>
                                <h2 className="data_text">
                                    give Sixers flexibility.
                                </h2>
                                <h3 className="data_text">Basketball</h3>
                                <h3 className="data_text">2022-6-15</h3>
                                <h3 className="data_text">Bob</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="click_to_view2">
                            <div className="column2">
                                <img
                                    className="image"
                                    alt="Article "
                                    src={require("./HomePage_Images/Harden.png")}
                                ></img>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* </a> */}
            </div>
            // </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share clear images, as I am not able to understand the problem.

Comment: I have the image of the problem at the top of the page where it says Image of Problem.

Comment: Yeah I can see that , but can you elaborate, how you want it to be fixed, the box should be centred or its contents like text and image.

Comment: Yes sorry about that. I uploaded an image of the desired outcome. I already made it look like how I want it. But as you can see in the first image I cant really center it if I expand the page because the contents inside of the bar is stretching to the right. So even though it looks perfect in my second picture, it is not scalable. if you stretch the page it will stay to the right

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving it a fixed width, try calculating the width with respect to the size of the screen. something like this:

```
.scrollmenu {
    width: calc(100vw - 10%);
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(236, 235, 235);
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
```